# React native error "unsupported BodyInit type" Why it occurs and how to solve it?

Tags: react-native

Please explain this error, why is it occurring

> fetch.js:231 Uncaught Error: unsupported BodyInit type
>
> at Response.Body._initBody (fetch.js:231)
>
> at new Response (fetch.js:390)
>
> at XMLHttpRequest.xhr.onload (fetch.js:437)

and how to solve it?